# How to use "a part of", "part of" and "parts of"?

Tags: plural-forms

Let's say I have five reasons for something.

If I would like to say one of five reasons, should I use

> A part of the reasons

or

> Part of the reasons

If I would like to say more than one reason, can I say

> Parts of the reasons

It sounds a bit of weird.

Any better ways to say this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP can use either ***One of the reasons*** or ***Part of the reason*** in the cited context. They're equivalent.

Note that Anglophones don't always bother to explicitly reflect the fact that there might be multiple "sub-reasons" in some context. There's nothing particularly unusual about [constructions like this...](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the%20reason%20is%20firstly%22)

> *The **reason** I don't like him is **firstly** he's ugly **and secondly** he's stupid.*

---

Although it's not actually "incorrect", we don't normally precede ***part of the reason*** by the indefinite article *(**a**)*. But I would say the pluralised form *part of the **reasons*** is *always* incorrect.